# MountDIR4Install folder taking 11 GB

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount

My pc is running Windows 10. I have a folder in my C drive called MountDIR4Install and this folder is taking 11.1 GB. In properties *size on disk* is 122MB. How come such a big difference?

Anyway the main point is what is this folder and why it taking so much space. After a little research on internet when I did - dism /get-MountedWimInfo then I saw:

Mounted images:

Mount Dir : C:\MountDIR4Install
Image File : F:\sources\install.wim
Image Index : 3
Mounted Read/Write : Yes
Status : Invalid

The operation completed successfully.

Now what do I do and how can I clean up as I am not using this folder.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: And what is the F drive?

Comment: As mentioned in post I am running Windows 10. F: is nothing right now, earlier it pointed to a usb stick.

Comment: Yes, this USB appears to have had a Windows installation disk image on it, Windows mounted it in that folder that you are seeing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Windows WIM installation image. You may need to plug the `F:` drive back in.

To unmount it:

```
dism /unmount-Wim  /MountDir:C:\MountDIR4Install /discard
```

If it fails:

```
dism /cleanup-wim
```

Then try again.

Source: **https://www.msigeek.com/2635/unmount-and-clean-up-a-wim-image-using-deployment-image-servicing-and-management-dism**

Comment: Thank you. The command dism /unmount-Wim  /MountDir:C:\MountDIR4Install /discard worked. However can you tell me what was this as I never mounted any image. Moreover in folder properties it showed size as 11 gb while size in disk showed as few MBs.

Comment: This is because you must have run the Windows installer for some reason, which then mounted an installation disk image. A mounted disk image doesn't take up much space on your disk while the actual size will be 11GB.